# Update setProgress during AJAX requests

Tags: android, ajax

I have a WebView in my progress which updates without issue during page requests, but I would like to have onProgressChanged work during AJAX requests.  Is this possible?

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                // Done?
                if ( progress == 100 )
                {
                    // Set
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that using Javascript interface. Check [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) for more information on how to call native android methods from javascript.

You can write your methods to set the progressbar indeterminate visibility to true/false from these methods and call these methods from your Ajax calls.